# Count() and VIEWS in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, view, count

`dbo.WScnt`? are views

The `tcnt1` is defined as `(INT, null)` in `WScnt1` view. The `tcnt1` values is a result from using `COUNT(*)` function.

Same for all other `tcnt`? values in each `WScnt`? view.

Statement:

```
SELECT  
    *,
    CONVERT(decimal(7, 2), ((tcnt2 / tcnt1) * 100)) AS Pct1,
    CONVERT(decimal(7, 2), ((tcnt4 / tcnt3) * 100)) AS Pct2
FROM 
    dbo.WScnt1, dbo.WScnt2, dbo.WScnt3, dbo.WScnt4;
```

RESULT:

```
tcnt1   tcnt2   tcnt3   tcnt4   Pct1    Pct2
--------------------------------------------
38347   12287   673 125 0.00    0.00
```

Question: why do I get 0.00 for Pct1 and Pct2?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: When you divide an int by an int, the result is an int. Converting after the division does not help you. You need to do that BEFORE division occurs.

Comment: yes basic math... changed to numeric

Answer (score 0):

Changed code not using VIEWS:

```
declare @myInt1 as NUMERIC(9,0);
set @myInt1 = (select COUNT(*) from dbo.Weekly);
```

Thanks marc_s!